# Scala: Remove none elements from map and flatten

Tags: scala, dictionary, flatten

I have a map:

```
Map("key1" -> Some("value1"), "key2" -> None, "key3" -> Some("value3"))
```

I want to remove all `None` elements and flatten the map. What is the easiest way to accomplish that? I only found this way:

```
Map("key1" -> Some("value1"), "key2" -> None, "key3" -> Some("value3")).filter(_._2.nonEmpty).map(item => (item._1 -> item._2.getOrElse(Nil)))
```

The result is:

```
Map(key1 -> value1, key3 -> value3)
```

Do you know a better way?

Comment: why not `filter` + `mapValues`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

My take using pattern matching is:

```
Map("key1" -> Some("value1"), "key2" -> None, "key3" -> Some("value3")).collect {
  case (key, Some(value)) => key -> value
}
// Map(key1 -> value1, key3 -> value3)
```

Collect acts like combined map + filter

Answer (score 21):

You can use for-comprehension + pattern-matching:

```
for((k, Some(v)) <- yourMap) yield k -> v
```

Comment: Now THAT is elegant. I never think of this :)

Comment: @felix I can't agree more

Answer (score 4):

Using partition over the map, like this,

```
val (flattened,_) = map.partition(_._2.isDefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

My take using for comprehensions:

```
val m = Map("key1" -> Some("value1"), "key2" -> None, "key3" -> Some("value3"))
for( (key,value) <- m if(value.isDefined)) yield (key,value.get)
```

Comment: By the way same could be written as `for((key, maybeVal) <- m; value <- maybeVal) yield key -> value`

Comment: @om-nom-nom or even `for ((k, Some(v)) <- map ) yield k -> v`

Comment: +1 because it also changes map type from `Map[String, Option[String]]` to `Map[String, String]`, essentially flattening not only values but also types.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the following helpers too, which allow for more compact syntax

```scala
implicit class RichPairedOptionIterableOps[A, B, Repr[_]](
    iterable: IterableOps[(A, Option[B]), Repr, Repr[(A, Option[B])]]
  ) {
    def collectWithSome: Repr[(A, B)] = iterable.collect { case (a, Some(b)) => a -> b }
    def collectWithNone: Repr[A] = iterable.collect { case (a, None) => a }
}
```

on your example:

```scala
Map("key1" -> Some("value1"), "key2" -> None, "key3" -> Some("value3")).collectWithSome
```