# Cut pairs with empty values from map

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I'd like to filter out all the pairs with empty values

```
val mapOfNotEmptyPairs: Map<String, String> = mapOf("key" to Some("value"), "secondKey" to None)
```

expected:

```
print(mapOfNotEmptyPairs)
// {key=value}
```

Comment: Essentially I'd like to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186057/scala-remove-none-elements-from-map-and-flatten but in kotlin

Comment: My question is to find a function in arrow-kt lib like cutMaybes from Haskell or flatten from Scala or compact from Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val mapOfNotEmptyPairs =
        mapOf("key" to Some("value"), "secondKey" to None)
            .filterValues { it is Some<String> } // or { it !is None } or { it.isDefined() }
            .mapValues { (_, v) -> (v as Some<String>).t }
```

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Kotlin

```
val rawMap = mapOf<String, String?>(
    "key" to "value", "secondKey" to null)
 
// Note that this doesn't adjust the type. If needed, use
// a cast (as Map<String,String>) or mapValues{ it.value!! }
val filteredMap = rawMap.filterValues { it != null }

System.out.println(filteredMap)
```

p.s When using Arrow Option

```
val rawMap = mapOf<String, Option<String>>(
    mapOf("key" to Some("value"), "secondKey" to None)

val transformedMap = rawMap
   .filterValues { it.isDefined() }
   .mapValues { it.value.orNull()!! }
```

p.p.s When using Arrow Option and their filterMap extension function;

```
val rawMap = mapOf<String, Option<String>>(
    mapOf("key" to Some("value"), "secondKey" to None)

val transformedMap = rawMap
   .filterMap { it.value.orNull() }
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Unfortunately, you have answered the wrong question.
Please consider in the question there is no null object, instead, you can find Option of String.

Filtering null values from the map is a completely different question. Additionally, it is a trivial observation that one can easily transform a case when Option is None to null, and then filter the map.

Comment: The type of your map is <String, String> and not <String, Option(al)<String>>, so I was assuming Some / None was a copy/paste issue from Scala or similar

Comment: Map<String, String> is the type I'd like to have as a result. Obviously, it doesn't compile the way I wrote it. So we can narrow down the question to find a function to transform from <String, Option<String>> to <String, String>. Ideally not using nulls.

Comment: For kotlin maps, arrow provides fiterMap, which filters out null values, see edit